# How to store files uploaded from client machine to jboss standalone directory?

Tags: spring-mvc, file-upload, jboss

I have requirement to store files uploaded (using spring mvc) from client machine to jboss standalone directory .Give step by step solution

Comment: You should write your own solution and post it here if you face any problem.

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I would give the community project called [Spring Content](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/) a try.  This project makes it very easy to handle files by injecting the service and controller implementations for you (so that you don't need to write them yourself).

Adding it would look something like this:

> pom.xml (assuming maven.  Spring boot starters also available)

```
    <!-- Java API -->
    <!-- just change this depdendency if you want to store somewhere else -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-content-fs</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- REST API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-content-rest</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

> StoreConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableFilesystemStores
@Import(RestConfiguration.class)
public class StoreConfig {

    @Bean
    FileSystemResourceLoader fileSystemResourceLoader() throws IOException {
        return new FileSystemResourceLoader(new File("/path/to/uploaded/files").getAbsolutePath());
    }

}
```

> FileStore.java

```
  @StoreRestResource(path="files")
  public interface FileStore extends Store<String> {
  }
```

And that's it.  The FileStore is essentially a generic Spring ResourceLoader.  The `spring-content-fs`  dependency will cause Spring Content to inject a filesystem-based implementation.  The `spring-content-rest` dependency will cause Spring Content to also inject an implementation if an `@Controller` that forwards HTTP requests onto the methods of the `FileStore` service.

So you will now have a fully functional (POST, PUT, GET, DELETE) REST-based file service at `/files` that will use your `FileStore` to retrieve (and store) files in `/path/to/uploaded/files` on your jboss server.

So:

`curl --upload-file some-image.jpg /files/some-image.jpg`

will upload `some-image.jpg` and store it in `/path/to/uploaded/files` on your server.

And:

`curl /files/some-image.jpg`

would retrieve it again.

HTH

The injected controller also supports video streaming too, in case that is useful.

With this you could also remove all of your controller and service code as it is no longer required.  Plus, as Spring Content is an abstraction over storage, in future, you could also shift to any of the other storage mediums supported by Spring Content; S3 for example.